# exporting "complete" data for former users

Tags: data-loader, data-export

I have an interesting request:

We sold a region to another company, and we'd like to give the departing salespeople their data.  It's a simple query to get everything the 4 users from that region created or own by userid.

The request is, "Get every account, contact, etc. that they had an activity on" for export.

Tooling-wise, I've got the excel add-in and Jitterbit dataloader, which is very cool.

I know how to do this in apex (relationship query up related records on activity) but I'm not sure how to go from that to CSV.  Advice?

Comment: Is giving them access to get their own data an option?  report + export?  this way, what they don't get, they can't come to you complaining ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there isn't a ton of data for the four users you could just write it out to a VF page.  You can format it for Excel with different sections as well.  See the [Using Content Types documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_styling_content_type.htm?).

```
<apex:page controller="MyDataExportController" contenttype="application/vnd.ms-excel#MyDataExport.xls">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Owned Contacts">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Contacts}" var="contact">
         <apex:column value="{!contact.Owner.Name}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!contact.LastName}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <!-- other types of records -->
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Alternatively, you could just use a flat unformatted csv:

```
<apex:page controller="MyDataExportController" contenttype="text/csv#MyDataExport.csv">
    <!-- write the header row -->
    <!-- write out all rows that you gathered in the controller -->
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done through Apex Batch, although you'll need a separate batch class for each object to look for, unless you want to add the target object as a parameter, or rewrite and redeploy the batch for each separate object. It could also be run for all 4 users at once, with 4 csvs, if you prefer.

- Be sure to use Database.stateful in the class declaration
- Take a userid as public Id variable or constructor parameter, unless you want to hard code it.
- Keep a running private String variable to store the CSV
- Querylocator: All Accounts [or Contacts or whatever] with related Tasks and Events that are owned or created by the specified user.
- For each Account, skip if there are no matching Tasks or Events. Otherwise, record the Account as a row in the persistent String variable in CSV format.
- In the finish() of the batch, email that CSV somewhere as an attachment.

My only concern here is if you have millions of records that will end up in that CSV; you may start to run into heap size or attachment size issues.